# Не сохраняет привязанную модель через form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, учу rails, решил написать магазин аккаунтов для себя. Есть две модели: Account, Image. В идеале нужно что б при создании аккаунта через `form_for` я мог прописать список изображений для аккаунта которые потом отображаются на странице(связь `has_many`, `belogs_to`). Но пока нужно что б мог указать одно изображение для аккаунта при создании.

**accounts_controller:**

```
 def create
        render json: params
     @account = Account.new(require_params)
     if @account.save
         redirect_to @account
     else 
         render :new
     end
    end
```

**_form**

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %><br>
<%= f.label :desc, 'descriprion'%><br>
<%= f.text_area :desc %><br>
<%= f.label :price %><br>
<%= f.text_field :price %><br>
<%= f.label :data %><br>
<%= f.text_area :data %><br>
<%= fields_for @account.images.build do |g| %>
<%= g.label :link %>
<%= g.text_field :link %>
<%end%>
<%= f.submit  %>
<%end%>
```

**schema**

```
 create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "desc"
    t.text     "data"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "price"
  end

  create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "link"
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "images", ["account_id"], name: "index_images_on_account_id"
```

Comment: Покажите модель Account

Comment: @cheops `class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10}
    validates :desc, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10}
    validates :data, presence: true, length: {minimum: 4}
    #validates :price, presence: true
    has_many :images
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы решите использовать `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (и подкрутите strong parameters, чтобы вложенные поля были разрешены), то вам придётся подкрутить форму, т. к. сейчас ваш `fields_for` определяет поля **в корне**, а не внутри другой модели, поля этих двух моделей лежат не *"одна внутри другой"*, а **рядом**.

```
<%= f.text_area :data %><br>
<%= fields_for @account.images.build do |g| %>
  <%= g.label :link %>
  <%= g.text_field :link %>
<% end %>
```

Видите неоднородность? `f.text_area` это поле `@account`. А `fields_for` не опирается на `f` и потому поля из билдера `g` не попадут в определяемый им `params[:account]`, а будут лежать рядом, в `params[:image]`.

Должно быть примерно так:

```
<%= f.text_area :data %><br>
<%= f.fields_for :images, @account.images.build do |g| %>
  <%= g.label :link %>
  <%= g.text_field :link %>
<% end %>
```

Это только один из вариантов определения подобной формы.

Пачка примеров [в документации Rails к методу `fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for), секция *Nested Attributes Examples*.

Comment: Спасибо, очень информативно.

Answer (score 1):

В модель `Account` добавьте `accepts_nested_attributes_for` для ассоциации `images`

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10}
  validates :desc, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10}
  validates :data, presence: true, length: {minimum: 4}
  #validates :price, presence: true
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

В `require_params` в контроллере следует добавить разрешение на редактирование `images`

```
def require_params
  params.require(:account).permit(
    :title,
    :desc,
    :data,
    :price,
    images: [:id, :link, :account_id, :_destroy]
  )
end
```

Comment: Не помогло, account сохраняет а image нет.
Вот create params:   
`{"utf8":"✓","auth..":"8jH0...==","account":{"title":"myAccountTitle","desc":"myAccountDesc","price":"4544","data":"lolol@ruggok.com:54GRg4tdgddd"},
"image":{"link":"http://wot-game.com//w.jpg"},"commit":"Create Account","controller":"accounts","action":"create"}`
Через консоль яб создал аккаунт так: 
u = Account.new title: "myAccountTitle", desc: "myAccountDesc", data: "lolol@r.com:54GRg", price: 4544 
u.save
u.images.create link: "http://wot-game.c..."

Comment: @VolodymyrLapan В account.images.errors.full_messages что-нибудь интересное есть?

Comment: Нет никаких ошибок, там просто сохраняет аккаунт без `image` наверное с `require_params` что то не так.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему через создание отдельной переменной для image.
        `def new
        @account = Account.new
         @image = @account.images.new
     end
     def create
     # render json: params
     @account = Account.new(require_params)
    if @account.save
         @image = @account.images.create(image_params)
         redirect_to @account
    else 
         render :new
    end
    end
      def require_params
  params.require(:account).permit(
    :title,
    :desc,
    :data,
    :price
    #image: [:id, :link, :account_id, :_destroy])
end
def image_params
params.require(:image).permit(:link, :account_id)
end`
   Если у кого то есть лучшие решения данной задачи, пожалуйста пишите в комментарии! Так как я только начинаюший и делаю как умею а не как правильно.